What "dropped: x async_ops, x resources" mean in `tokio-console`

I can't find a description of this in tokio-console docs. Is this red mark:
dropped: 4974 async_ops, 5030 resources
normal?
What does it mean?
Here are the resources:

There's only 1 task running:

Someone else brought up this discussion but no one else has answered yet. I want to know if this is normal, after the task is running for a good while (an hour or so).
